# Is there a plugin for KOrganizer that allows me to access google calendar?

Tags: kde, google-calendar, calendar, organizer

Where can I find such a plugin?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

yes, [akonadi-kde-resource-googledata](http://packages.ubuntu.com/karmic/akonadi-kde-resource-googledata), and its in the repos

```
sudo apt-get install akonadi-kde-resource-googledata
```

Comment: How do I connect Korganizer to my goggle account?

Comment: @txwilkinger, that's changing the goalposts somewhat, no?

Comment: @ifraone: True :D

Comment: any info on how to configure this plugin?